# Weird behavior when using websockets

Tags: javascript, c#, html, iis, websocket

I have written a simple websocket server/ client.
The server is written using C# (System.Net.WebSockes) and client is javascript
(although server technology is irrelevant because I have tested it with signalr and got the same error during the handshake of websocket transport).
The problem is that:

1- on some clients I can easily connect to server and works very well.

2- on some other clients I get an **error code 1006** during handshake 
      and in these clients when I turn on a proxy app such as PSiphon it can connect to the server. However, it gets disconnected after **about 6 seconds**.

I'm really super confused, and finally after hours of trying I have decided to put a question here.
I don't think that it`s related to code, but I put it here anyway.

```
    var url = 'ws://' + location.host + '/socket';
    var socket = new WebSocket(url);
```

**Update 1:** i have contacted system administrator (Hosting Company) and they said it might be because of the ISP of clients. if that`s the case i would appreciate any tip to make sure if there is some kind of proxy server that causes the trouble?

**Update 2:** as @vtortola mentioned i created a self signed certificate and added to website (IIS and Plesk). there was some improvement but still getting disconnections

Thanks in advance..

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization) Was it 'wired' or 'weird', btw?

Comment: are all test clients are on local host?

Comment: I really don't think anybody can tell you anything useful based on your given information. "On some clients" isn't really helpful, nobody can spot what is the difference on "some clients".

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen no, i have tested on hosting space (in production invironment).

Comment: @jAndy yes, that is possible, but there might be some who knows some tricks about tracing packet and check if there is some proxy server that causes trouble.

Comment: Do you need to register ` 'ws://' + location.host + '/socket';` in IIS?

Comment: i do`nt think so, only config needed by iis is activating websocket which is already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It smells like proxy issues to me. Use secure connections (`wss://`) and check if it gets better. Basically, if some of your clients are behind proxies, the WebSocket connections can misbehave in many unexpected ways.

[How HTML5 Web Sockets Interact With Proxy Servers](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers).

Comment: i have created a self signed certificate and installed on website, what happened is that it now passes the handshakes and connects but immediately disconnects after about 2 seconds.

Comment: If it does happen just to a handful of them, it maybe some kind of proxy killing connections because it thinks they are half dead connections. There are still devices in the wild that think that a HTTP connection that lasts longer than usual is just some kind of malfunction. The proxy maybe in those clients ISP network and not in yours.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to some how trace websocket packet and find out which server in the route is making trouble . for example using "tracert" command to find all servers in between and then pinging individual servers (using websocket) to check if it`s causing problem or no?